# Groupby and Aggregate over a pandas column with list as elements, and get unique values in list

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 1, 3],
        "values": [[111, 121, 131], [211, 221, 281], [111, 191], [301, 321]],
    }
)
# df
id  values
1   [111, 121, 131]
2   [211, 221, 281]
1   [111, 191]
3   [301, 321]
```

I want to get the following after groupby and aggregation step

```
id  values
1   [111, 121, 131, 191]
2   [211, 221, 281]
3   [301, 321]
```

I am using the following, but it is giving me an error -

```
new_df = df.groupby(["id"]).agg({"values": lambda val: set(val)}).reset_index()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it -

```
df.groupby('id')['values'].sum().apply(lambda x: list(set(x))).reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
    id  values
0   1   [191, 131, 121, 111]
1   2   [221, 211, 281]
2   3   [301, 321]
```

Answer (score 2):

**This should work**

replicate your example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 1, 3], 'values': [[111, 121, 131], [211, 221, 281], [111, 191], [301, 321]]})
```

Solve question

```py
df = df.groupby(by='id').sum()
df[['values']] = df[['values']].applymap(lambda x: set(x))
```

The output

```py
    values
id  
1   {121, 131, 191, 111}
2   {281, 211, 221}
3   {321, 301}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`df.explode`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) then use [**`GroupBy.unique`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html) here.

```
df.explode('values').groupby('id')['values'].unique().reset_index()
    id  values
0   1   [191, 131, 121, 111]
1   2   [221, 211, 281]
2   3   [301, 321]
```